# how to convert string contains list to regular list in python?

Tags: python, airflow

I have an the following function in Apache Airflow:

```
from airflow.utils.email import send_email
send_email(to=['a@mail.com','b@mail.com'],
           subject=....)
```

This works great.

Now I don't want to hard code the email list so I save it as a configurable field that the user can change from his UI.
[image]

So I change my code to:

```
NOTIFY_LIST = Variable.get("a_emails")
send_email([NOTIFY_LIST],
           subject=....)
```

But this doesn't work.

When I do:

```
logging.info(NOTIFY_LIST)
logging.info([NOTIFY_LIST])
logging.info(NOTIFY_LIST.split(','))
```

I see:

```
'a@mail.com', 'b@mail.com'
[u"'a@mail.com', 'b@mail.com'"]
[u"'a@mail.com'", u" 'b@mail.com'"]
```

So my problem is that:

```
['a@mail.com','b@mail.com']
```

and

```
[NOTIFY_LIST]
```

isn't the same.

How can I fix this? I tried any conversion I could think of.

Comment: What error/exception you are getting?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM The error is related to wrong email but it's because the type is wrong. I need the to=  to contain this type ['email','email2']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion to try the following;

`logging.info(NOTIFY_LIST.replace("'", "").split(','))`

The problem here is that the elements in the list contain quote marks.

Comment: This solution will fail if the strings have an `'` anywhere else, luckly email adderesses can't have an `'` in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer will fail if there's an ' in the midle of the strings, to fix that I'll use [`str.strip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp):

```py
logging.info([s.strip("' ") for s in NOTIFY_LIST.split(',')])
```

Comment: these are hard codded mailing list. while your answer is pythonic correct there is no need to add complexity of code for edge cases that will never be reached. single quote is invalid charterer for email address so it cant be in the middle of the string.